# How can I get the rows from SHOW PROCESSLIST using MySQL Connector for .NET or Dapper?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector, dapper

I need to parse the running queries on my MySQL server. What is the easiest way to retrieve the result of SHOW PROCESSLIST from within MySQL Connector for .NET, or using [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)?

Maybe something like (with Dapper):

```
var rows = connection.Query("SHOW PROCESSLIST");
```

Comment: well, what happens if you do exactly that? do you get [n] rows with Id, User, Host, db, etc? (i.e. `foreach(var row in rows) { Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row.Id, row.User); }`)

Comment: Definitely need to try, thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of most MySQL meta-commands are represented in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` pseudo-database:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
```